# Sql запрос в среде Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe7

У меня есть таблица dbf, и мне программно через Delphi нужно объединить 2 столбца в 1 пустой с условиями. Условие таковое, если kod_op = 10..19 и 30...39 и nod_nazn не равно 0, то nod_nazn должен записаться в пустой столбец dnazv. Второе условие точно такое  если kod_op = 10..19 и 30...39 и nod_nazn равно 0, то dor_nazn должен записаться в пустой столбец dnazv.
И вот мой не рабочий запрос:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='update input.dbf set dor_nazn=dnazv where kod_op in(
    '+''''+'10'+''',
    '+''''+'19'+''',
    '+''''+'30'+''',
    '+''''+'39'+'''
)'+' and  nod_nazn='+''''+'00'+'''';                    
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='update input.dbf set nod_nazn=dnazv where kod_op in(
    '+''''+'10'+''',
    '+''''+'19'+''',
    '+''''+'30'+''',
    '+''''+'39'+''')'+' and  nod_nazn<>'+''''+'00'+'''';
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: `10..19` это `in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)`

Comment: Да, и не только 10...19, но и 30...39

Comment: Kodop>=10 and kodop<=19

Comment: при чем тут делфи вообще, если вопрос чисто про БД и sql ? и на кой вы числовые значения  в кавычки заключаете.

Comment: Как я написал выше, тут это запрос производится в программе написанной в Delphi!

Comment: дак вы сначла просто запрос к СУБД напишите, а потом уже делфи приязывайте. Пока что у вас проблема с самими запросом. Как уж написано выше, решаться она должна в виде `nod_nazn = 0 AND ( (x >= 10 and x <= 19) OR (x >= 30 and x <= 39))`